# How can you pre-fill form data before creating/sending an envelope when using templates

Tags: docusignapi

I want to prefill some fields that are included on the template level.

Lets say, for example, that I want to prefill the employee name and some other info from our application's existing records before sending out the document included in the template to be signed.

How could I get a list of all the form fields.

With pdfs I normally use the itextSharp library to get all the AcroField (pdf form fields) for a given fileName and set them to whatever values I want using the SetField() method.

I'm looking for a way to do something similar with files hosted in DocuSign

Could be I'm missing something very obvious

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a [step-by-step code example](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/) showing you how to do exactly this.

The JSON will look something like this:

```
"templateId": "9e35d343-6942-4756-b7aa-XXXXXXXX",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "joe.doe@doooeeee.com",
        "name": "Joe Doe",
        "roleName": "employee",
        "tabs": {
            "checkboxTabs": [{
                "selected": "true",
                "tabLabel": "ckAuthorization"
            }, {
                "selected": "true",
                "tabLabel": "ckAgreement"
            }],
            "listTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "tabLabel": "list",
                "value": "green"
            }],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "groupName": "radio1",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": "true",
                    "value": "white"
                }]
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "text",
                "value": "Jabberywocky!"
            }, {

        // .....
```

Comment: I couldn't find it. Could you please post a link

Comment: I just saw it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Set%20template%20tabs) that you can try out. The API Request Builder app includes translation to C#, Java, Node.JS, PHP, Python, Ruby and more.